# "Get out of" vs "get out from"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference

I used this sentence yesterday, " Get out of my class". A student suddenly pointed out saying isn't it in correct and further added that get out from my class should be the correct way to do it .

My question is which one is correct and in case both of them are, when is of used and when is from used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get out of is the correct expression, in this context. For e.g. we got out of the building as fast as we could, when we heard the fire-alarm.

Alternative word is leave/leaving--We left the classroom, after we were done with the assignment.

Please note that--get out of my class expression implies anger on the part of the instructor. You should instead use expression such as-please take it/your business outside.(if students are disturbing by talking over you)

Comment: The expression *get out from* does exist in sentences such as, "Get out from under the mountain of debt you have accumulated!"  But I agree with Rohit: *get out of* is correct in the original poster's question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @AmritAwasthi You are welcome. You can accept the answer as correct answers, if you think it answers your need.